# combobox search in html

Tags: java, jquery, html, css

I am developing a mobile shop web application in php. It having a combobox which may contain hundreds of elements. So very difficult to search an option from that list.

***How i can create a combobox with a text editing field.?***

Comment: muahahaha Finally! A use for my jQuery Plugin https://github.com/kmacey1249/heftybox/tree/dievardump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using JQuery, I think using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) is a good way to enhance your combo box.

The plugin adds a text box so that users can easily search your combo list. In addition, you might also wish to use optgroups to group the selections for easier readability.

Chosen is very flexible, so you shuold be able to tailor it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks allot. It working properly in IE-08,09,Mozilla,chrome. But not working in IE 07.

Comment: This plugin for searching or add multiple options.what i should do when i need to add if it is not exit. Means if not find in searching it act as a text box.

Comment: If that is the case, I think you are looking for the "autocomplete" pattern. In that case, this plugin would be more suitable: http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

Comment: Using this query i can add choose multiple options. But I dont want like this. I just need drop down list which can useful to fined element but it cant select multiple values.